# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: this.resolveComponent is not a function | Inertia, Django & Vue

Tags: django, typescript, vue.js, inertiajs

I have a Vue page (`FormTest.vue`):

```
<template>
  {{ user }}
  <form @submit.prevent="submit">
    <input type="text" v-model="user.first_name" label="First name" />
    <input type="text" v-model="user.last_name" label="Last name" />
    <button type="submit">Save</button>
  </form>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import {User} from '@/types/users';
import {router} from '@inertiajs/vue3';

const props = defineProps<{
  user: User;
}>();

function submit() {
  router.post('/form-test', {
    first_name: props.user.first_name,
    last_name: props.user.last_name,
  });
}
</script>
```

Then a Django view:

```
def form_test(request):
    user_instance = get_object_or_404(CustomUser, pk=request.user.id)

    if request.method == "POST":
        form_data = dict_to_querydict(json.loads(request.body))

        form = CustomUserForm(form_data)

        if form.is_valid():
            user_instance.first_name = form.cleaned_data["first_name"]
            user_instance.last_name = form.cleaned_data["last_name"]
            user_instance.save()

    return render(
        request,
        "FormTest",
        props={"user": CustomUser.objects.get(id=request.user.id)},
    )
```

The update works, it correctly stores the values in the db and on the page I see them change within the `{{ user }}` as well.

Just running into an error in the console upon submission:

```
router.ts:452 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: this.resolveComponent is not a function
    at C.setPage (router.ts:452:33)
    at router.ts:390:21
setPage @ router.ts:452
(anonymous) @ router.ts:390
XMLHttpRequest.send (async)
dispatchXhrRequest @ xhr.js:251
xhr @ xhr.js:49
dispatchRequest @ dispatchRequest.js:51
request @ Axios.js:148
wrap @ bind.js:5
visit @ router.ts:342
post @ router.ts:527
submit @ FormTest.vue:20
(anonymous) @ runtime-dom.esm-bundler.js:1328
callWithErrorHandling @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:158
callWithAsyncErrorHandling @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:166
invoker @ runtime-dom.esm-bundler.js:278
Show 13 more frames
```

Somewhere within the `render` function something goes wrong I believe, but I'm not sure how to handle it. Anyone any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

I figured out the problem. This is actually due to a difference between these two packages:

```
@inertiajs/vue3
@inertiajs/inertia-vue3
```

Honestly very confusing. Make sure you use the NEW variant. The latter hasn't been updated in over 2 years.

Use: `@inertiajs/vue3`

In my case I was using the old one in my `main.ts`, which caused the error. So I updated it with the following config (for those wondering):

```
import {createApp, h} from 'vue';
import {createInertiaApp} from '@inertiajs/vue3';

const pages = import.meta.glob('./Pages/**/*.vue', { eager: true });

createInertiaApp({
  resolve: (name: string) => {
    const pageImport = pages[`./Pages/${name}.vue`];
    if (!pageImport) throw new Error(`Component "${name}" not found`);
    return pageImport as any; // Explicit type assertion
  },
  setup({ el, App, props, plugin }) {
    createApp({ render: () => h(App, props) })
      .use(plugin)
      .mount(el)
  },
})
```

Hope this helps! Cheers.